# Ruby on Rails and Redis - cache working intermittent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

I am using redis to cache my data in rails, it works the first time and caches the data but after the 5 mins expires I the following error

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method []' for true:TrueClass):`

This is what I use to cache the data, a custom method monkey patched into the redis class.

```
@avg_results = $redis.cache(
    :key => "#{current_member.id}-#{@group.id}-avg",
    :expire => 300, # seconds, 5 minutes
    :timeout => 5  # seconds
  ) do
    Group.all.to_json
  end
unless @avg_results.nil?
  @avg_results = JSON.load @avg_results
end
```

This is the monkey patch

```
class Redis

  def cache(params)
    key = params[:key] || raise(":key parameter is required!")
    expire = params[:expire] || nil
    recalculate = params[:recalculate] || nil
    expire = params[:expire] || nil
    timeout = params[:timeout] || 0
    default = params[:default] || nil

    if (value = get(key)).nil? || recalculate

      begin
        value = Timeout::timeout(timeout) { yield(self) }
      rescue Timeout::Error
        value = default
      end

      set(key, value)
      expire(key, expire) if expire
      value
    else
      value
    end
  end

end
```

So my question is this, why and I getting the error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method []' for true:TrueClass):` ?

`EDIT`

I think I have tracked the issue down to a memory leak, If my server is out of memory when redis has expired and I am saving the new data back to redis `true:TrueClass` is set? instead of the data from the database. Can I patch this? or do I need to track down the leak?

Comment: can you add the full error stack ??